# How best to turn a JArray of type Type into an array of Types?

Tags: c#, json.net

I've got a `JArray` that represents the json substring `[1,2,3]`. I'd like to turn it into an `int[]` instead.

What's the correct way of doing this? The best way I've found so far is to do the following:

```
int[] items = new int[myJArray.Count];

int i = 0;
foreach (int item in myJArray)
{
    items[i++] = item;
}
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
int[] items = myJArray.Select(jv => (int)jv).ToArray();
```

Comment: I prefer this method. It's brief and more elegant.

Comment: I think I prefer this answer, too. I sometimes overlook LINQ.

Comment: It's also possible to avoid casting: myJArray.Select(jv => jv.Value<int>()).ToArray();

Comment: this assumes `using System.Linq;` and possible `using System.Collections.Generic;` or you will get 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' has no definition for 'Select' (are you missing a reference?)

Comment: This is also now possible as `myJArray.Cast<int>().ToArray();` It's slightly less verbose.

Answer (score 96):

```
myJArray.ToObject<int[]>();
```

You can also specify HashSet, List etc.

The accepted answer relies on .NET's conversion - this technique uses JSON.NET's own in addition to what .NET can provide so works with more scenarios.

It's also faster as it isn't using a generator & closure for the LINQ operation.

Comment: The question is: does it work with arrays in the form of MyCustomContract[]?

Comment: This worked for me while the accepted answer did not.  I have no idea why, JSON.Net appears to require voodoo magic to find the correct syntax to parse a given object.

Comment: The accepted answer requires that the type can cast using the built-in .NET facilities. 

ToObject tells JSON.NET to do the conversion which has a few extra conversion routines available beyond the basic .NET ones.

Comment: After searching for some time finally somebody with some solid solution. Thanks for this.

Comment: Thanks!  I found this also works with an array of arrays too! 
 Ex. `myJArray.ToObject<int[][]>();`

Answer (score 4):

A cast needed first for me:

```
((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray)myJArray).Select(item => (int)item).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty weak because you have to convert back into a string, but if you are doing something quick and dirty, where the performance hit won't matter, I use the below method. I like it because I don't have to write any code to map properties between json/JObject and my POCO's.

```
public static class JsonExtensions {
    public static T As<T>(this JObject jobj) {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jobj));
    }

    public static List<T> ToList<T>(this JArray jarray) {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jarray)); 
    }
}


    [Test]
    public void TestDeserializeRootObject() {
        var json = @"{ id: 1, name: ""Dwight"" }";
        var jfoo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

        var foo = (jfoo as JObject).As<Foo>();
        Assert.AreEqual(1, foo.Id);
        Assert.AreEqual("Dwight", foo.Name);
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestDeserializeArray() {
        var json = @"[
            { id: 1, name: ""Dwight"" }
            , { id: 2, name: ""Pam"" }
        ]";

        var foosArr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        Assert.IsInstanceOf<JArray>(foosArr);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, (foosArr as JArray).Count);

        var foos = (foosArr as JArray).ToList<Foo>();
        Assert.AreEqual(2, foos.Count);
        var foosDict = foos.ToDictionary(f => f.Name, f => f);

        Assert.IsTrue(foosDict.ContainsKey("Dwight"));
        var dwight = foosDict["Dwight"];
        Assert.AreEqual(1, dwight.Id);
        Assert.AreEqual("Dwight", dwight.Name);

        Assert.IsTrue(foosDict.ContainsKey("Pam"));
        var pam = foosDict["Pam"];
        Assert.AreEqual(2, pam.Id);
        Assert.AreEqual("Pam", pam.Name);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] items = new int[myJArray.Count];

for (int i=0; i < myJArray.Count;i++)
{
    items[i] = (int)myJArray[i]
}
```

this is the fastes solution you can do. The classic `for` is a bit faster than the `ForEach` as you access the item by the index(the foreach behind the scene uses the IEnumerator interface)

or if you prefer:

```
JsonArray arr = JsonConvert.Import("[1,2,3,4]");
int[] nums = (int[]) arr.ToArray(typeof(int));
```

Comment: While I was hoping for something built into the JArray class that I was overlooking, at least this confirms with me that I haven't.